# Customizing a Jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am using a jquery plugin called Hight charts that needs to specify in my html a div with #container and then this put in script tags generate some chart :

```
$(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            options: {...},
            }
        });

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            other_options:{...}
    });
});
```

Since I need to call this plugin for each element of a dynamic list of my web page, I want to create a plugin that wraps this one. Before caring of DOM's nodes traversal, I put to test

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.ChartPlugin = function() {
Highcharts.setOptions({
            options: {...},
            }
        });

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            other_options:{...}
          });
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

But now when I call to test $.ChartPlugin(); nothing happens, could someone tell me where I am going wrong ?

Edit : I removed '.fn' and it worked but I don't understand why

Comment: Well that is strange. I usually extend the libraries for me but never encountered such problem and definitely never had a problem with '.fn'.

Comment: Found this. http://asimilia.wordpress.com/2008/12/17/jquery-extend-confusion/ So i learned something bcoz of your question. Thanks.

Comment: So great, if you learned something, you can upvote :) thank you for the link